How to increment a pointer to RVV type?
gcc errors out on the following code with "arithmetic on pointer to RVV type"
Incrementing an int* is fine, then why is it an error to increment a pointer of RVV type? How to increment a pointer to RVV type then?
#include "riscv_vector.h"

void foo(void *in, int *p)
{
    vuint8mf8_t *in_t = (vuint8mf8_t*)(in);
    vuint8mf8_t *v = in_t++; // error: arithmetic on pointer to RVV type
    int *q = p++; // no error
}

$ gcc -O2 -march=rv64gcv
error: arithmetic on pointer to RVV type 'vuint8mf8_t'

Please explain what you want to achieve with that. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

You are using a post increment, so even if it did work, v would have the value of in_t before the increment was done.  Is that what you want?

@Yunnosch clarified what i'm trying to achieve. @cup the difference in pre/post increment is unrelated to my question. Just like we can increment a pointer to int, how can we increment a vuint8mf8_t*?

I think you did not. You repeated that you want to increment the pointer. I would like you to take one logical step back, consider that this might be a XY problem and tell potentially helpful users what you want to achieve by incrementing. Because there might be ways to achieve your actual goal without incrementing the pointer.

Hi, @A.K.. Since RVV types don't have a fixed size, it isn't possible to increment a pointer to them. In general, you really don't want to use pointer to RVV types.
Instead, you should use a pointer of element type, so in your case uint8_t* and add the result of the appropriate vsetvl to that, if you want to iterate over an array. Use the appropriate load store instructions/intrinsics (vse*/vle*) to load data from a pointer into a vector type.
I encourage you to look at the example code in the intrinsics repo: https://github.com/riscv-non-isa/rvv-intrinsic-doc/tree/main/examples
